# What does Mailgun SMTP code 451 PC LOAD LETTER mean?

Tags: smtp, mailgun

I have a PHP script which connects to Mailgun using SMTP.

I got this error a few times, and would like to find out what it means:

`451 While saving message: PC LOAD LETTER; retry your request again`

- It has been working reliably for a long time.
- There was only one Google search result for `"PC LOAD LETTER" mailgun` and it was not relevant.
- There were Google search results for `"PC LOAD LETTER" smtp` but nothing relevant.

Comment: "PC LOAD LETTER" was an HP printer message. SMTP 451 return code is a temporary failure which can be retried. In that context, "LOAD LETTER" could be a pun.

Comment: It's a fairly well known meme, and at first it did make me smile. But in this context it's unclear if it intended to have meaning or if it is just Mailgun's sense of humor. It doesn't seem to be documented.

Answer (score 2):

It is, indeed, a bit of a pun.
The “retry your request again” is the important part. We were likely experiencing intermittent connectivity issues internally  that exhausted our retry attempts.

Comment: I can confirm, It is a fun throw back to the movie "office space", and the printer error that occurred during the movie. The RFC does not specify what the exact error for a 451 should be, and "internal server error" was boring, so we got a little creative.